# Custom addition method fails during string interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#it's python 3.2.3
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, point):
        self.x += point.x
        self.y += point.y
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'point(%s, %s)' % (self.x, self.y)

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test1 = [point(0, i) for i in range(-1, -5, -1)]
        self.test2 = [point(i, 0) for i in range(-1, -5, -1)]

        print('%s\n+\n%s\n=\n%s' % (self.test1[0], self.test2[0], self.test1[0] + self.test2[0]))

test = Test()
input()
```

The output of this program is

```
point(-1, -1)
+
point(-1, 0)
=
point(-1, -1)
```

But it should be

```
point(-1, -1)
+
point(-1, 0)
=
point(-2, -1)
```

But if I do

```
print(point(-1, -1) + point(-1, 0))
```

It works perfectly

I want to know why, and how to solve this problem

p.s. sorry if my english is bad :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `__add__` function modifies the left-hand argument to `+`. For example:

```
>>> x = point(0, 0)

>>> x + point(1, 1)
point(1, 1)

>>> x
point(1, 1)
```

You should change `__add__` to be like

```
def __add__(self, oth):
    return point(self.x + oth.x, self.y + oth.y)
```

Comment: Nothing like pasting code and having someone else beat you by a few seconds.  My mistake was clearly taking the time to type "er" in "other".. ;-)

Comment: But, OP's code returns the original object, and indeed works in another context. I don't think this is a sufficient explanation.

Comment: I agree with @Marcin - though this is the only obvious problem in the OP's code, it can't be the entire story - he only adds them once, and doesn't print the LH point after that, only before. The side effects shouldn't be noticed by this particular test case. Unless tuple literals can be evaluated out of order?

Comment: @lvc The tuple isn't evaluated out of order AFAIK, but the first element is a reference to the object, and the entire tuple is evaluated before `%` gets it to do the string formatting. So the tuple is `(new_point1, point2, new_point1)` as seen by `%`. Plus, if you run the code, it works now. :)

Comment: What OP calls `__add__` (+) is actually implemented as `__iadd__` (+=) because it mutates an operand. Imagine his example was simplified to print('%s\n+\n%s\n=\n%s' % (a, b, a += b)) and it should be clear what is going on.

Comment: @Dougal So, there is an error in the output which your answer does not diagnose.

Comment: @Marcin Huh? The error is that the `__add__` function had incorrect semantics, the output is fine.

Comment: @Dougal No. The output is not as it should be in two ways, which makes this more confusing.

Comment: @Marcin What's wrong with the output? It's a perfectly reasonable way to print that out (equivalent to `(a, b, a+b)` except they're in a list), and once the semantics are fixed, it works perfectly. I agree that the particular way in which things were printed out made it slightly confusing to diagnose, but we understand the reason now and there's nothing wrong with anything other than the original definition of `__add__`.

Comment: @Dougal Look at the code, then look at how the first point is printed. The value is not the same as it would after removing the `iadd`.

Comment: @Marcin more confusing, maybe, but it doesn't make @Dougal wrong - the error is, indeed, entirely caused by `point.__add__` having side effects and returning `self`. Because it returns `self`, the first and third points in the output will always be the same object.

Comment: @lvc This answer is incorrect in that accepts the incorrect premise of the question, and does not explain how the incorrect implementation causes this problem.

Comment: @Marcin "doesn't explain how", I'll grant you. That makes it inideal, not incorrect.

Comment: @lvc It leaves the reader with an incorrect impression of how the code should operate, and how it will operate after the prescribed change is made.

Answer (score 3):

You say the output should be:

```
point(-1, -1)
+
point(-1, 0)
=
point(-2, -1)
```

In fact it should be:

```
point(0, -1)
+
point(-1, 0)
=
point(-1, -1)
```

Because you are creating that first point with `[point(0, i) for i in range(-1, -5, -1)]` (note the `x` parameter is `0`).

This is a consequence of `(self.test1[0], self.test2[0], self.test1[0] + self.test2[0]))` being evaluated - the addition modifies the first point in that tuple (they are the same object). This is also why your second example works correctly (or appears to) - you only print the modified object once.

The implementation of `__add__` you provide is suitable for `__iadd__` to implement the `+=` operator. A correct implementation should create a completely new `point` object:

```
def __add__(self, oth):
    return point(self.x + oth.x, self.y + oth.y)
```